# Inside my asp.net core MVC web application how i can make the recaptcha a required field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am working on an asp.net core mvc web application, and i have added the following field to show google recaptcha version 2:-

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="recaptchaCallback" data-sitekey="@ViewData["ReCaptchaKey"]">
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 //code goes here
 @section Scripts {

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>}
```

and inside my action method i am checking if the user select the recaptcha or not, as follow:-

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchNPI(ContactinfoCreate ci)
        {

            //add uncompleted entry
            ViewData["ReCaptchaKey"] = _configuration.GetSection("GoogleReCaptcha:key").Value;
            if (!ReCaptchaPassed(
            Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"], // that's how you get it from the Request object
            _configuration.GetSection("GoogleReCaptcha:secret").Value,
            _logger
            ))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Please enter CAPTCHA");
                
            }
```

but on the client side how i can ake the recaptcha required filed, so the user can not submit the form unless he/she select the recaptcha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine whether clicks recaptcha before submit by triggering the **data-callback** method of recaptcha, and then **adding a hidden contro**l.

After clicking recaptcha,assign a value to **hidden control** in data-callback method, and then `judge the hidden value in the form submit method` to determine whether this form can be submitted.

```
<form method="post"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="@ViewData["ReCaptchaKey"]" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div> 
            <input type="hidden"  value="" id="isClickCaptcha" />
            <span class="text-danger" id="validationText"></span>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-US"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var recaptchaCallback = function () { 
        $("#isClickCaptcha").val("yes");
    };

    $("form").submit(function () {
        if ($("#isClickCaptcha").val() == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#validationText").text("Please enter CAPTCHA!");
            return false;
        }

    })
</script>
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: Simple, clear, concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in javascript I imagine you have a function called recaptchaCallback which is responsible to perform the form submit. It should look like this

```
function recaptchaCallback(token) {

}
```

well, just add

```
if (!token || token === '') {
    alert("Could not verify that you are a human");
    return;
}
```

Comment: the post back function will work when you check the captcha and not when you submit the form..

Comment: i also added the function as mentioned in your reply.. but it did not force the required validation..

Comment: what do you exactly mean with when the user submits the form without recaptcha? in v3 isn't it invisible?

Comment: i am using version 2... the recaptch is showing "I am not robot"..